# How to move a file to trash with Del key in Gnome 3.14.1 / Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome-shell, nautilus

By defualt, in the Gnome's Nautilus version shipped with Jessie,
one needs to press Ctrl+Del to move a file to trash or Shift+Del to remove it permanently.

I know there was a [fix](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=916646#p916646) for that in older Gnome versions
and that the behavior is [back and improved in Gnome 3.16](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/gnome-316-released-with-new.html).

However I guess I am "stuck" with Jessie's Gnome for a while and I don't find a way to bind the simple Del key to what Ctrl+Del does.

Comment: Maybe they've changed it to prevent accidental deletions? I found it strange at first, but now I feel comfortable with it. Why don't you try to live with it?